# How to display the traverse of a linked list (doubly linked list)?

Tags: c++, c++11

My assignment is to create a list in our main function and then display those numbers as a list. Then, we are supposed to show that it also traverses by displaying for example a reverse of that list. My problem is that I cannot seem to get the traversing part to display.Basically, anything that does not have a comment line after, the professor had already provided. Anything that has a comment line, I added. Thanks

```
    #include <iostream>

     using namespace std;
     struct Node {
        int data;
        Node* next;
        Node* prev; //
        Node(int d=0, Node* p=0, Node* n=0) : data(d), next(p), prev(n) {} //
        Node* insert_after(int value);
        Node* delete_();
        void display_list_after() ;
        void display_list_prev();
        };

    Node* Node::insert_after(int value) {
    Node *p = new Node(value);
    Node *n = p; //
    p->next = next;
    p->prev = this; //
    next = p;
    return p;
   }
    Node* Node::delete_(){ //
    Node *p = this;
    Node *n = 0;
       if (prev != 0){ //
          prev->next = next; //
            n = prev; //
        }

       if (next != 0) { //
        next = prev->prev; //

        if (n == 0){ //
            n = next; //
          }
      }
         delete p;
         return n; //
      }
      void Node::display_list_after() {
      Node *head = this;
        while(head != 0) {
       cout << head->data << " ";
        head = head->next;
      }
        cout << '\n';
     }

       void Node::display_list_prev() {
          Node *tail = this; //
          while(tail != 0) { //
          cout << tail->data << " "; //
         tail = tail->prev; //
      }
       cout<<'\n'; //

      }
     int main(){
     Node *head= new Node(10);
     Node *tail = head->insert_after(40);
     Node *p = head->insert_after(20);
     p = p->insert_after(25);
     p = p->insert_after(30);
     p = p->insert_after(35);
     p->insert_after(40);
     head->display_list_after();
     tail->display_list_prev(); //
       }
```

Comment: Have you figured out why or at least *where* your code is crashing? Tip: your code doesn't even compile due to some 'n' variable..

Comment: basically, the display_list_after works. it will display "10 20 25 30 35 40". The display_list_prev doesnt work at all. Edit: Really? It compiles for me. And it runs as well. Im using the putty compiler on a linux server

Comment: IN `Node::insert_after` you commented the __n__ variable and then you are using it.

Comment: My bad, that shouldnt have been commented. It still compiles for me though

Comment: Since you are tagging c++11, you should use nullptr as in Node(int d=0, Node* p=nullptr, Node* n=nullptr).

Comment: your `tail` variable declared in main() is set to NULL then never gets set, but you dereference it. there seems to be multiple issues with your code. for one thing you mix node as a class containing the data with the operations on them, in this case it would be cleaner to have the operations outside Node and then operate on the whole list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is in the node insertion routine:

```
Node* Node::insert_after(int value) {
    Node *p = new Node(value);
    Node *n = p; //
    p->next = next; // this is right (usually NULL)
    p->prev = prev; // this is wrong (this node is the previous of the next one)
    next = p;
    prev = n; // this is also wrong (previous is not the next one)
    return p; // this is right since this is the next node
    return n; // this is the same stuff and will never get executed
   }
```

change it to:

```
Node* Node::insert_after(int value) {
    Node *p = new Node(value);
    Node *n = p; //
    p->next = next;
    p->prev = this; // this is the previous node for the next one
    next = p;
    return p;
}
```

and `tail` needs to be initialized too:

```
tail = p->insert_after(40);
```

<kbd>[Try it out](http://ideone.com/Ie2XoI)</kbd>

Comment: This really helped thanks! However, there is a slight problem; it only displays 40 and 10 which are the last and first values respectively. It doesn't display the values in between. Im going to update what I have in my code

Comment: @EricRangil if you followed what I wrote it should display the entire chain of values: http://ideone.com/Ie2XoI

Comment: EDIT: Nvm i found my problem. I didnt change head to p in the intialization of tail.